# Is there a group policy or permission to create local shares?

Tags: group-policy, windows

I have some custom windows services which need the ability to create and remove local shares. In trying to lock down security, I also don't want to run the services as administrators. Is there a specific policy/permission that I can configure in order to allow these services to manage local shares?

Comment: When you say "local shares" do you mean on multiple servers/computers/etc? Also what version of Windows Server?

Comment: Server 2003 and 2008. By local shares, I mean creating shares on the server that the Windows Service is currently running on.

Comment: I still haven't been able to find a solution to this. Anyone have any ideas?